# GCSToGCSOperator source objects with wildcard to target specific files

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-storage

I have a task in a gcp ariflow dag to move files from one google storage directory to another after done integrating those files. There are two groups of files: one starts with 'S', and the other with 'T'.

So I have used following code to do the job:

```
source_objects1 = f'{input_path}/S*'
source_objects2 = f'{input_path}/T*'
destination_path = f'{archive_path}/'

task_mv_rest_files_to_archive = GCSToGCSOperator(
    task_id=f'Move_files_to_archive',
    source_bucket=my_bucket_name,
    source_objects=[source_objects1, source_objects2],
    destination_bucket=bucket_name,
    destination_object=destination_path,
    move_object=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

The problem is after the move the files lose their first letter. For instance, file 'S20231103' will become '20231103'.
So, how should I use the wildcard to achieve my goal using GCSToGCSOperator ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match_glob` parameter described in the [documentation examples](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/gcs_to_gcs.html#copy-multiple-files):

```
copy_files_with_match_glob = GCSToGCSOperator(
    task_id="copy_files_with_match_glob",
    source_bucket=BUCKET_NAME_SRC,
    source_object="data/",
    destination_bucket=BUCKET_NAME_DST,
    destination_object="backup/",
    match_glob="**/*.txt",
)
```